# How to convert feet and inches to decimal feet?

Tags: fractions, unit-of-measure

What is the proper way of converting feet inches to decimal feet?

For example

**15 ft - 4, 1/8 inch 
= 15.34'**

I understand that the 15 get's moved but how do you take 4 1/8" and turn that into 0.34?

Comment: How many inches go into a foot? Or, more directly relevant here: How many feet is a single inch?

Comment: @Arthur thank you I completely forgot about the last portion of the conversion I knew it was 4 + (1/8) = X but completely forgot about X / 12

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are $12$ inches in a foot, so $4.125$ inches$=4.125$ inches $\frac {1\text { foot}}{12 \text { inches}}=00.34375 \text { feet}$

Answer (score 2):

Got it worked out.

**15 ft - 4 1/8 in = 15.34 ft**

15 ft get's moved over so we have 15

Now we convert the inches to ft

**4+(1/8) 
= 4+0.125
= 4.125**

Now we convert that into ft by dividing it by 12 as 12 in = 1 ft

**4.125 / 12 = 0.34375'**

And now let's convert it to 2 decimal points.

**0.34375 = 0.34'**

And for the final let's take the original 15 ft and add it up.

**15 + 0.34 = 15.34' (15.34 ft)**